# Parse XML description of a state-flow model in python

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, xml-parsing, for-xml-path

I'm searching for a package which can parse XML description of stateflow model to a finite state machine specification representation in python.I want to extract the data from XML file.Which package in python is suitable for me? Can you suggest?

Comment: There are lots of xml parsers in python ... `xml.etree.ElementTree`, `xml.sax`, `lxml` (third party) ... What are you looking for exactly?  Is there some code that you can share that would illuminate the problem for us?

Comment: Sir,I want to translate the XML description of a stateflow model of simulink model to an intermediate representation which identifies the states,transitions and junctions of the model.Here I'm giving the intermediate format which i want..Yup there are lot of packages are available.So i have to choose the right one to get this as output."%token state5
%token state4
%token state3
:
trans19 ( state5 -> state5 ) null
trans18 ( state4 -> state4 ) null
trans11 ( null -> state3 ) "Set"
trans17 ( state5 -> state3 ) "[brake]"
trans16 ( state4 -> state3 ) "Set | Resume" Please suggest one package sir